# Jest vue.js unit test throws TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'hasOwnProperty'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I am trying to get the hang of Vue.js tests with components that use Vuex and Vue Router, following documentation [here](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/vuex.html#testing-with-a-real-vuex-store), but get `TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'hasOwnProperty'` I am using the Vue UI to run the test (output below), but I cannot reproduce (thanks to @tony19 for showing how) on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vuex-router-jest-dijqok?devtoolsheight=33&file=tests/unit/AppNav.spec.js).

[image]

**AppNav.spec.js**

```js
import {shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils'
import store from '@/store'
import router from '@/router'
import AppNav from '@/components/AppNav'

describe('AppNav', () => {
  test('logged out shows login button', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(AppNav, {
      global: {
        plugins: [store,router]
      }
    })

    await expect(true).toBe(true)
    //await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
    //expect(wrapper.find('button').isVisible()).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

**AppNav.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/">
      Home
    </router-link>
    <router-link to="/event-list" v-if="loggedIn">
      Events
    </router-link>
    <router-link to="/event-create" v-if="loggedIn">
      Create
    </router-link>
    <router-link v-if="!loggedIn" to="/login" class="button">
      Login
    </router-link>
    <button v-else type="button" class="logoutButton" @click="logout">
      Logout
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { authComputed } from '@/store/helpers'

export default {
  methods: {
    logout() {
      this.$store.dispatch('logout')
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...authComputed
  }
}
</script>
```

**store.js**

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import { createLogger } from 'vuex'

const store = createStore({
  plugins: [createLogger()],
  state: {
    user: null,
    events: null,
    count: 0,
    nextPageURL: null,
    previousPageURL: null,
    event: null
  },
...
export default store
```

Comment: Unit tests should be stubbing out the store, as the store itself should have its own unit tests that are independent of any component. Have you tried [Testing with a mock store](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/vuex.html#testing-with-a-mock-store) instead?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vuex-router-jest-k2tifc?file=tests%2Funit%2FAppNav.spec.js).

Comment: Wow, I am blown away by your demo and stackblitz! (☝ ՞ਊ ՞)☝ I imported my full store file and I too cannot reproduce the error.  Must be in my versions? I am using the standard vue-ui to build and run my project tests.

Comment: Fixed with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66629237/cant-run-hello-world-test-in-vue-with-vue-test-utils  Updated my Vue dependency to `"vue": "^3.0.6"` from `^3.0.0-0`  @tony19 deserves the credit for eliminating all other possibilities.

Comment: @metalaureate yes, this was the fix, thx. It might help people like me if you answer your own question and mark it as the solution. I almost missed this comment here.